# Displaying a progress bar & text in a cell of a data grid (XAML)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridview, progress-bar

How can I display an animated progress bar within the contents of a cell of a datagrid, with text in the foreground.

For instance, I want to display "Uploading..." and have the progress animated behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting both a TextBlock and ProgressBar inside a grid, so that the TextBlock appears over the progress bar.

Like so:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar />
    <TextBlock Text="Uploading..." />
</Grid>
```